# Unicode character encoding

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to output Unicode characters(Ukrainian, Belorussian) from `DownloadString(url);`. By this time, it outputs only English and other languages are displayed like symbols.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string method = "messages.get";
        string param = "out&count=10";
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/"+method+"?"+param+"&v=5.31&access_token="+myAuth.Token1+"";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        RootObject response = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(RootObject));

        textBox2.Text = response.response.items[0].body;
    }
```

How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

use `client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`